# Restore content of corrupted system file

Tags: networking, files, restore, data-corruption

**How can I restore the content of one of Ubuntu's system files?**

*Background: I've turned the file `/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-wait-online.service` into an unreadable binary file (I have no more acces to it) using `chmod`, I'm just a beginner...*

I was wondering if there's a hidden copy of system files or the file is somewhere available in the internet. Or somebody using Ubuntu/Debian can just post the content of the file (assuming it's in it's original state).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What makes you believe that you *"turned it into an unreadable binary file using chmod"*? what are the symptoms, exactly?

Comment: `chmod` can't turn anything into binary, it just changes permissions.

Comment: Anyway, this is my copy: http://pastebin.com/raw/pgy1Ge6T

Comment: @BharadwajRaju - I know the usage of `chmod`, but in the explorer the file was shown as binary file, and I had no access to it, not even with sudo  (and I could not open it in gedit)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From debian-8 :

```
[Unit]
Description=Network Manager Wait Online
Documentation=man:nm-online(1)
Requisite=NetworkManager.service
After=NetworkManager.service
Before=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nm-online -s -q --timeout=30
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```